# How to cope with 'invalid literal for int() with base 10' when changing a type (pandas dataframe)?

Tags: python, pandas, types

I have column in Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"consume":["11", "14", "11,5", "12,6"]})
```

and I would like to change type of this Series. Currently, it has type `object`, but I need it to be `float64` or `int64`. How can I change the type of column? Should I change it on `int64` or `float64`?

When I try to do it like this:

`data['consume'] = data['consume'].astype('int64')`

I get an error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4,2'`

Comment: Did you read this from a file with pd.read_csv? If so specify `decimal=','` when you read the file

Comment: @adriano1234 Please never write `Please do not send links to other answers I have already checked it` to avoid getting downvoted.  Add links to useful information you checked and discuss why it doesn't work in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it is obvious that you can not cast to integer cause you have a comma in your strings. (btw do you really need int64 ?? that is too big)
I guess float would be fine so you can use this line to do it, practically replace comma with dot and then cast it to float64 (float32 can be even better)

```
data['consume'] = data['consume'].str.replace(',','.').astype('float64')
```